# Null result expected real values

Tags: sql, servlets, jdbc

When I am trying to get values from database the result set is giving me false and the values are null.

```
public boolean login()
{
    try
    {
        String p="SELECT * FROM DEMONEW WHERE EMAIL=? AND PASSWORD=?";
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(p);
        pstmt.setString(1,EMAIL);
        pstmt.setString(2,PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("email :"+EMAIL + "and" +"password:"+PASSWORD);
        ResultSet res = pstmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("res :"+ res.next());
        while(res.next())
        {
            NAME = res.getString(1);
            System.out.println("NAME FROM MODEL :" +NAME);
            AGE=res.getString(2);
            System.out.println("age FROM MODEL :" +AGE);
            LOCATION=res.getString(3);
            System.out.println("email FROM MODEL :" +EMAIL);
            EMAIL=res.getString(4);
            System.out.println("location FROM MODEL :" +LOCATION);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am expecting the values in database but getting null.

Comment: firstly, check your `SELECT * FROM DEMONEW WHERE EMAIL=? AND PASSWORD=?` statement, replacing the ? parameters with the values passed through execution time, to check that the values indeed exist in your db. It is probably a typo in your input

Comment: What does this line `System.out.println("res :"+ res.next());` prints ?

Comment: it will print either false or true. I used it because I want to know where the problem is. And it always giving me false

Comment: Remove this `System.out.println("res :"+ res.next());` line from your code , because it will move your cursor to next row , and when you will print `while(res.next())` <- this will always return false. Because you are getting only one row from table .

Comment: Simple use `if(res.next()){ //getting values }else{  //error }`